# How do I delete the previous character in vim?

Tags: vim

Given this line of text in vim, where the cursor is located at the caret, and the user is in command mode:

```
sales_tax: row["sales tax"] ,
____________________________^
```

What is the fastest way to delete the space between the `]` and the `,`?

Comment: are you in insert mode or command mode?

Comment: Command mode. An answer that addressed how to do it in both modes would be a bonus. Updated question to specify command mode.

Comment: If you are in insert mode, you can simply press the backspace key, but a useful trick to know is ctrl-o where you can run 1 command-mode command and then immediately return to insert mode. See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Ctrl-O_instead_of_Esc_in_insert_mode_mappings . @Axnyff's answer is the best here though.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should simply use `X` (which is <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>)

Answer (score 5):

Simple `hx` (meaning move left + del char) in command mode is also an option.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス my question stated, "What is the fastest way."

Comment: @jerzy `Use your downvotes whenever you encounter (...) an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.` Is this answer incorrect ? it could be useful for some beginners.

Comment: @jerzy There is usually many ways how to achieve some goal in Vim. I read your question and in terms of "fastness" my suggested solution `hx` is as fast as the other `X` solution (two keyboard hits). I am working in Vim everyday and personally, "hx" suits me better so I just wanted to mention it for you so you can decide ;)

Comment: Actually `h`+`x` is faster than `Shift`+`x` since the `h` is right there in the home row. `Shift`+`x` is instead the *appropriate* command because was meant for that: `Shift`+`x` delete the previous character like `Shift`+`p` paste in the previous column.

Answer (score -1):

There are already two great answers here.  Let's assume you really want the backspace button to delete the previous character while in normal mode.  You can change that behavior with this line in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
nnoremap <silent> <backspace> X
```

This will tell vim to issue the `X` command (as noted in [Axnyff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41491791/519360)) whenever you hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in normal mode.  I think I like this; it now lives in my `~/.vimrc`.

There are precious few available keys for mapping and <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (mapped by default to <kbd>l</kbd> and <kbd>h</kbd> respectively) seem decent candidates for other functionality. I find this mapping intuitive and helpful, but that's a subjective call. It may or may not be desirable to you.

If you worry about what might happen without the mapping, it'll be pretty straightforward: you'll move the cursor onto the character you want to delete (and then you'll hit <kbd>x</kbd>, resulting in the same number of keypresses as <kbd>h</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>).

Comment: Personally I find backspace to match really well in my mind with the `<c-^>`/`<c-6>` functionality. `nnoremap <bs> <c-^>`

Comment: If `backspace` is now `X`, then what is `backspace`? I, personally, avoid remaps that will conflict with default behavior, so I don't get used to nonstandard functionality when I ssh into a machine that doesn't have my vimrc.

Comment: By default, the backspace key doesn't do anything interesting in normal mode; it's mapped to `h` (move cursor left) by default (see `:help <bs>`), just as the spacebar is mapped to `l` (move cursor right) by default. You can see the other commenter here remapped it to play with his buffers.